# Passing arguments are empty

Tags: c#, .net, process, processstartinfo

I pass some arguments from WPF app to  WinForm apps like this.

```
int processID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = FileManager.AppDirectoryName + "\\" + winformApp;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("Param1={0}", processID );
p.Start();
```

But in other application I cannot see any args.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
 // Get start arguments 
 var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 var args = process.StartInfo.Arguments; // It is empty. Why is it??
```

Any clue?

Comment: try with `var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: Derp, nm, I'm thinking console.  Ignore me. doesn't `static void main()` usually have a `string[] args` param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

Returns

> A new Process component associated with the process resource that is running the calling application.

This new component will have an empty startinfo member. Just use

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Instead.